# Solutions for a diophantine system equations

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-geometry, diophantine-equations

Does there exist any integer solution for the diophantine system of equations below:

$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
x^2=a^2+b^2-ab
\\
y^2=a^2+b^2+ab
\end{array} \right. ,$

**Notice:** I know that the two equations above are two similar ellipses with $x=y$ axis that transform to eachother by $\frac {\pi}{2}$ rotation angle, but unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with algebric geometry to solve this system.

Here for example I've find a solution for the first equation for $(x,a,b)=(7,8,3)$ by changing it to a simpler form $m(m+k)=n(n+2k)$ where $(x,a,b)=(n+k,m+k,m)$, but this solution doesn't hold in the second equation.

Now it is clear that we are searching for integer solutions of the intersection points of these two ellipses.
[image: two similarly rotated ellipses of two equations above for (x,y)=(7,9)]

Comment: Is it a question? What's your question? Also, I think you know that's important that you show your attempts for to solve this problem.

Comment: @АлександрПальма lets see my efforts on this problem, i'll soon explain where it stems from.

Comment: Your equations and description/picture of your problem do not match. The equations you've written down don't describe an intersection of ellipses. Which one is your true question?

Comment: @kreiser my question is the integer solutions of the equations system ,but i can't see why the intersection points don't represent the solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$ \left( x^2 + xy + y^2 \right) \left( x^2 - xy + y^2 \right) =  x^4 + x^2 y^2 + y^4 $$

Page 19 In Mordell's book *Diophantine Equations* includes a proof that the only solutions  for
$$ x^4 + x^2 y^2 + y^4 = z^2 \; , \; \gcd(x,y) = 1 $$
integers have either $x=0$ or $y=0$  and the other $\pm 1.$ This is formula (7'), given as an example of (7), that being
$$ x^4 + kx^2 y^2 + y^4 = z^2 \; , \; \gcd(x,y) = 1 $$
Chapter 4 is called **Quartic Equations with only Trivial Solutions**

Comment: Great, but as I do not have access to the book, would you please explain more, especially what is "$pm1$"? I mean I didn't understand at last whether there is untrivial solution or not?

Comment: @MasM no, there is not

Comment: There appears to be a bit more work to connect your statements to the statements in the problem. In particular, all the equations in the post are quadratic, not quartic.

Comment: @KReiser but the product of the two binary quadratics is the above quartic. I guess it is $a,b$ above. Then the product of the two squares is some other square, here $z^2$

Comment: Oh, right. It might be worth making an edit to make this more explicit in order to save others from falling in to the same gap I did.

Comment: So I appreciate any edit you may do in order to help resolving the question and the answer in a more clear way, and it also may cause of removal of the two downvotes on this post just for better approach of future people's referral.Thanks.